# `coverage combine` results from different containers?

Tags: docker, coverage.py

To reproduce:

1. Create a project with two services.
2. Test each service in its own container using `docker-compose run --rm --entrypoint='pipenv run coverage run […]' [service-name]`.
3. Combine the results using `coverage combine first-service/.coverage second-service/.coverage` outside the containers.
4. Run `coverage report`, or worse, `coverage html`.

These last commands can't find the source files because the .coverage files were saved with the absolute paths of the source files within each container, which does not match the host.

Is there a way to make coverage reporting work in this scenario? Any of the following would be useful if possible:

1. Record relative paths in .coverage and prefix the paths in the combined .coverage file with the directories containing the original .coverage files.
2. Include the source files in the .coverage files. Especially useful if reporting happens after the files have been changed.
3. Heuristically detect the closest-looking path per file in .coverage at reporting time.
4. A setting like [`paths`](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-4.4.2/config.html#paths) which can map /src/app from one .coverage to the service1 directory and /src/app from the other .coverage to service2.

Non-solutions:

- Not using Docker.
- Running both test suites in the same container.
- Writing a script to modify the combined .coverage file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use separate `paths` declarations per service:

.coveragerc-service1:

```
[paths]
source =
    service1
    /src/app
```

.coveragerc-service2:

```
[paths]
source =
    service2
    /src/app
```

This necessitates two `coverage combine` calls:

```
coverage combine --append --rcfile=.coveragerc-service1 service1/.coverage
coverage combine --append --rcfile=.coveragerc-service2 service2/.coverage
```

(`rm .coverage` first to enable re-running.)

Comment: I don't understand all this yet, but does it help that you can have multiple `[paths]` entries?  Why do both services use "/src/app"?  Shouldn't each app have its own path?

Comment: I don't expect declaring two `source`s with the same origin would work. As for your second point, they run in different containers, so their paths should definitely not be dependent on each other.

Comment: I'm not saying their paths should depend on each other, but why are they they same?  It's different code from different repos.  Why aren't they /src/app1 and /src/app2?  If for some reason you need to be able to refer to them uniformly for some other tooling, you can also have a symlink from /src/app to /src/app1

Comment: They are not in different repos, and why would I **enforce** deploying to different paths on each service? Symlinking just complicates the matter, because now you're saying sometimes use one path and other times use the other path.

Comment: OK, maybe I don't understand the Docker mindset.  To me, it's strange to have two different source trees running as the same path. One reason to use different paths is because other tooling (like coverage.py) might think that paths have meaning.  Or maybe I still have it wrong. I'm glad you found a solution.